# ASP.NET Razor C# SQL Database Dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, razor, webmatrix

I am hoping someone can help me.  I am sure this is quite simple, but I have spent many hours searching for the answer and nothing seems to be working.  I have a CSHTML file in Microsoft WebMatrix with Razor/C# code and HTML markup as well as a basic SQL table.  I would like to put a dropdown list which displays the results of a SQL query.  Below is my code.

```
@{

var db = Database.Open("QualityMonitoring") ;
var listAgent = "SELECT Agent FROM Data";

}
```

How do I create a dropdown list to display the results in my markup?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your dropdownlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a SelectedListItem list and bind a dropdownlist to it. Extend the code to:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("QualityMonitoring") ;
    var listAgent = "SELECT Agent FROM Data";

    List<SelectListItem> agentdropdownlistdata = new List<SelectListItem>();
    bool isSelected = false;
    foreach(var item in db.Query(listAgent)){   
        agentdropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.AgentName,
            Value = item.AgentID.ToString(), 
            Selected = isSelected
        });
    }
}
```

And in the markup use html helper to bind the data:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Agents", agentdropdownlistdata)
```

Comment: Thanks afzalulh, I have applied your code and markup, but I am getting the following error. Compiler Error Message: CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

 Source Error:
Line 7:      foreach(var item in db.Query(listAgent)){
Line 8:          isSelected = false;    
Line 9:          agentdropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectList Item
Line 10:         {
Line 11:             Text = item.AgentName,

Comment: Sorry for the typo! It should be SelectListItem, not SelectList Item. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked, although I had to comment out Value = item.ID.ToString(), as this produced an error on rendering. How would I make it so no default value is selected?  It can say "Please Choose..." for example?

Comment: You can add a new SelectListItem as selected: `agentdropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "Select one",Value = "0", Selected = true });` outside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and tell me if the problem gets solved:

> DropDownlist.DataSource = listAgent;

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  listAgent is the variable which contains the SQL statement.  Do I put your suggestion in the code or the markup?  I am not sure how to create the dropdown list in the markup. Since it is Razor, I am thinking something which would require @ before it.

Comment: Well i am not quite familiar with razor, but the code above i showed you must be put in the code section not markup

Comment: @afzalulh, how can I give this dropdown list a name so I can pass its value to a variable?

Comment: In the design view select the control and change its name in properties.